# Angular bootstrap datetimepicker localization, change language

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I found out that UI Bootstrap date picker supports localization by including a i18n js file for the specific language for example:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.2/i18n/angular-locale_fr-fr.js"></script>
```

But this makes the language fixed to French. Is there any way I can switch between 2 languages say English and French on click of a button??

Answer (score 0):

We have an outstanding issue in the UIBS datepicker such that the labels are bound using one-time binding syntax.  You can track [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4692) for more information as well as using your own template to remove the one-time binding syntax to switch languages.